# copying a directory from one location to another in the same server but the script to copy is present in another server

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh, scp

I am trying to write a script in a server which copies a directory present in another server and paste it in the same directory but at different location, what is the correct format for the SCP command for this process.

Comment: "same directory but different location" - is it another sub directory in the same server or the same directory on another server ?

Comment: Instead of `scp` you can use the `ssh` command in this way: `ssh user@host 'cp -R /dest/dir /target/dir`'

Comment: another sub directory in the same server

Comment: Show us what you tried thus far: that may render your specific problem more clearly. With `scp`, you can specify source and destination on remote hosts, so I do not see your specific problem as long as you specify correct pathnames to the remote host.

Comment: check out this guide https://www.shellhacks.com/ssh-execute-remote-command-script-linux/

Comment: The solution shared by @pa4080 worked for me, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complete the task, you can use the `ssh` command in a way as this:

```bsh
ssh user@host 'cp -R /source/dir /dest/dir'
```

Thus instead of opening a login shell the `ssh` client will execute the command within the quote marks on the remote system and then will close the connection. In this case the remote system will process the data.
In addition you can capture the output of the command and save it as a local file if you need, for example:

```bsh
ssh user@host '<remote command>' > /local/path/file.log
ssh user@host '<remote command> 2>&1' > /path/file.log  # capture the remote errors
```